# Something planned for the future but which is already investigated, what's the right word? consider, envisage?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

I have a sentence like

> But also more fancy products such as artificial skins are envisaged.

Which is the right word to put in the place of **envisaged**? As far as I know there are no products yet on the market but such products are planed, and there is research going on to realize such products. However there are other products (using the same technique) which are less advanced and will likely be commercialized earlier.

Now is *envisage* the right word or does it imply something too utopian? Are words as consider better? I guess in French (which is not my mother-tongue) I would have used the word *envisager*, but I feel the English counterpart has not exactly the same meaning.

Comment: [*Envisioned*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/envision).

Comment: @snailboat: Some people think [***envision*** and ***envisage*** have different meanings](http://grammarist.com/usage/envision-envisage/), but I think it's really just [a matter of UK/US usage preference](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76972/)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ah, thank you for telling me!  I wasn't aware usage differed.  Collins, a UK dictionary, gives almost identical definitions for both words, but it also gives an additional meaning for [*envisage*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/envisage): "to form a mental image of; visualize; contemplate"

Comment: @snailboat: Both words were pretty much non-existent a century ago, but since then [UK usage has stuck to "envisaged"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+envisioned%2Che+envisaged&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=), whereas [US usage has massively switched to "envisioned" since the 1970s](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+envisioned%2Che+envisaged&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=). I find it frankly inconceivable that this is anything to do with some supposed difference in meaning. It's just regional preference.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I guess it just goes to show that we're just not so *in your face* as you guys. :)

Comment: @snailboat: It may be a completely meaningless "chance divergence", of course. Or perhaps it's just that whereas Americans obviously know the word *vision*, they don't live so near France (it's those [cheese-eating surrender monkeys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheese-eating_surrender_monkeys) who are more *in our face/visage* than yours! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a problem of mismatched [registers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_%28sociolinguistics%29) in OP's example. As pointed out in comments above, [***envisage*** and ***envision*** are simply UK/US regional variants with no discernible difference in meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76972/envision-vs-envisage). But they're both ["50-cent words"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45683/value-in-cents-of-big-words) that clash with OP's rather slangy/informal *fancy = sophisticated, complex*.

OP should decide whether to go for (1) *normal/informal* or (2) *formal*, and stick to one register...

> 1: ...more *fancy* products such as artificial skins are *planned*.
>    2: ...more *sophisticated* products such as artificial skins are *envisaged* (US, *envisioned*).

---

Note that I don't mean to imply *planned* or *sophisticated* are "informal" or "formal" usages above - like most English words, they're "neutral/normal" (neither formal nor informal). It's only the specific words *fancy* and *envisaged/envisioned* that denote "level of formality" in my examples.

As a general principle, I think both non-native speakers *and* native speakers without high linguistic competence should avoid trying to produce "formal" phrasings, because [careful speakers/writers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0684826321) are more likely to notice the inevitable mistakes, and *judge them more harshly.* If you're not sure exactly how to use a "fancy" word, play safe and use "ordinary" words (just avoid "informal" usages as appropriate).

Comment: +1 Also:  *fancier*, not *more fancy*, at least cisatlantically.

Comment: As a non-native english speaker I have some difficulties to fully understand your answer. OP=?. The sentence will be in the introduction of my thesis (in Physics). I guess sophisticated might be a better choice than fancy. so envisaged might not imply that the realization is too far in the future?

Comment: @user2758804: I don't think there's any single word you could use at the end of your sentence that would reliably disambiguate between *planned in the **near** future*, and *planned in the **distant** future*, if that's what you mean. As it's a thesis, you should definitely avoid the informal "fancy" here. Both *envisage* and *envision* will be understood by any competent native speaker, and they're unlikely to notice or care which you use. Some people may think *planned = intended/expected*, where *envisaged/envisioned = allowed for/possible* (but might not *actually* happen).